# NodeMCU ESP8266 doesn't write in serial

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I've been working on semi IOT project that is a simple dimmer with lamp lighting control. When I want to set the value that I receive from the Android app to serial, it's not working correctly. All the hardware is properly set because for example this code is working:

```
int i =0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  delay(100);
  for (i =1 ; i<9 ; i+=1) {
    if(Serial.available()) Serial.write(i);
    else Serial.println("esp:serial w not available");
    Serial.println(i);
    delay(3000);
  }
  for (i =9 ; i>0 ; i-=1) {
    if(Serial.available()) Serial.write(i);
    else Serial.println("esp:serial w not available");
    Serial.println(i);
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

This code works correctly. You can increase and decrease lamp light, but when I want to receive a value from Android like this it doesn't work:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

IPAddress staticIP832_240(192, 168, 43, 240);
IPAddress gateway832_240(192, 168, 43, 1);
IPAddress subnet832_240(255, 255, 255, 0);
const char *ssid = "G3";
const char *password = "@4112303";
WiFiServer server(80);
int value = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  delay(3000);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  Serial.println("Start");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while ((!(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED))) {
    delay(300);
    Serial.print("...");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  WiFi.config(staticIP832_240, gateway832_240, subnet832_240);
  WiFi.hostname("G3_ESP");
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Your IP Addressees:  ");
  Serial.print((WiFi.localIP()));
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Your Gate Way:  ");
  Serial.print((WiFi.gatewayIP().toString().c_str()));
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Your Host Name:  ");
  Serial.print((WiFi.hostname()));
}

void loop() {
  try {
    // Check if a client has connected
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (!client) {
      return;
    }
    // Wait until the client sends some data
    Serial.println("new client");
    while (!client.available()) {
      delay(1);
    }
    // Read the first line of the request
    String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.println(request);
    client.flush();
    // Match the request
    if (Serial.available()) {
      Serial.write(2);
      Serial.write(8);
      Serial.write(0);
    } else {
      client.println("serial not available in first show up");
    }
    if (request.indexOf("/up") != -1) {
      if (Serial.available()) {
        Serial.write(8);
        client.println("up is successful");
      } else {
        client.println("up not successful");
      }
      return;
    } else if (request.indexOf("/down") != -1) {
      if (Serial.available()) {
        Serial.write(2);
        client.println("down is successful");
      } else {
        client.println("down not success");
      }
      return;
    }
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    client.println("<html>");
    client.print("lamp value is : ");
    client.print(value);
    client.println("<br><br>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/up\"\"><button>up</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/down\"\"><button>down</button></a><br />");
    client.println("</html>");
    delay(1);
    Serial.println("Client disonnected");
    Serial.println("");
  } catch (Exception exception) {
    client.println("exception has occurred ");
    client.println("_____________________________");
    client.println("this exception:");
    client.println(exception);
    client.println("_____________________________");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the baud rate to Serial.begin(115200); on both the code and the serial monitor.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa 
I've try another baud rate but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your use of `Serial.available()` makes no sense.

Comment: its pretty awesome that when i use simple for loop serial is available but when i want to use web request serial not available!